# Scripts loaded by iframe not released

Tags: jquery, iframe, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-9

This is for an IE9 intranet jQuery app. An iframe is dynamically created with the src pointing to some other intranet app (cross domain though) which loads ~5 meg of js. The iframe is a child of a "window" type container with a "close" button. There is no interaction between the "host" app and the iframe app. When the iframe is removed from the DOM, none of the js seems to be released. Each load increases the memory by roughly the same amount. I have no access to the other apps.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var i = 0;

function App2() {
    if ( $('#container' + i)[0] == undefined ) {
        i++;
        $('<div id="container' + i + '">').appendTo('body');
        $('<iframe id="if' + i + '" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/desktop/desktop.html">').appendTo('#container' + i);
        $('<input id="clb' + i + '" type="button" value="Close"/>').appendTo('#container' + i);
        $('#clb'+ i).click(function(){$('#container' + i).remove();});
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="App2();" value="App2"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if wold be nice to show some code ... if you really need some help ... i don't know mediums here :)

Comment: Sorry, thought that was obvious from my description. I am new to this - will try to add some code.